# Problem with Date format when save an xls file as xlsx

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following information in a xls file: ( the date format is dd/mm/yyyy):

```
-14/01/2020
-10/01/2020
-9/01/2020
-8/01/2020
```

When I save it as xlsx it results changing the data which days are between 1 and 9:

```
-14/01/2020
-10/01/2020
-01/09/2020
-01/08/2020
```

I try using a Visual Basic script and the following code:

```
Columns("DataColumn:DateColumn").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
```

Note:Apparently my xls have a version problem, and when I open it displays a message "File format and extension do not match".

Comment: Is your xls file actually text? Many people generate a CSV and simply give it an xls extension. Excel will open this (with a warning) but it is not a true xls file.

Comment: Mm I am not sure if it is text. I download from  web page. If it is text, what I can do?

Answer (score 0):

In your source xls file, date format is dd/mm/yyyy and in your target xlsx file, it is mm/dm/yyyy.

Just try to keep the same format dd/mm/yyyy in xlsx file. It should work.

```
Columns("DataColumn:DateColumn").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
```

Answer (score 0):

as_xlsx.QUERY2SHEET(p_sql => 'select sysdate+rownum d1 from cat where rownum < 9',
**p_UseXf => true**
);

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).